# How to give my website SSL certification

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I readed, that in the 2017 seo trend, websites need ssl certification.
What is this, and how can i give it to my site?

It means, that http://test.com will be https://test.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a free SSL certificate with https://letsencrypt.org/
They have a step by step tutorial depending upon which server you use!

and yes, SSL sites rank a little higher than non-SEO ones